# Am I allowed to cut the music from the audio library of YouTube?

Tags: editing, audio, youtube, music

Thank you for helping me! I have a very simple question but I just can't find the answer to it: **Am I allowed to cut the music from the audio library of YouTube** (the one in YouTube studio)? So for example if the music is 2 min long but your video is only 1 min long, are you allowed to delete the rest?
I searched here, on YouTube and on the internet. I seem to not get an answer anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube hosts a couple of different licenses, the most common is YouTube Audio Library License, where you're allowed to edit/cut it down.

Second most common is Creative Commons, there in most cases you are allowed, expect in the case of ND (= Symbol)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry, what ND-symbol are you talking about?

Comment: Creative Commons ND stands for No-Derivatives, meaning you cannot adapt the work. You can only use it to it's full extend as is. But I doubt YT Library will have any of that, it's most likely all CC-By. (CC-By is shown by a CC and an icon of a person, ND is shown by an equal sign) check https://creativecommons.org/ for more details on this.